# make in one query a count and max over partion by in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle SQL I have a table with

| userid | qualification | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Qual1 | 01/01/2020 |
| One | Qual2 | 01/01/2022 |
| Two | Qual1 | 01/01/2021 |
| Three | Qual2 | 01/01/2022 |

I want to have per user id:

- the count of qualifications
- the most recent qualification

So for this example I want:

| userid | qualification | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Qual2 | 2 |
| Two | Qual1 | 1 |
| Three | Qual2 | 1 |

I thought to use something like this:

```
select userid, 
    count(qualification)OVER (PARTITION BY userid) as count_qual,
    MAX(qualification) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date desc) as qual_id
from Qualificaitons
```

but it returns me two lines for `userid` One

Comment: select DISTINCT as you are showing all userid rows by select userid,........

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MAX(..) KEEP (DENSE_RANK ..)` aggregation function:

```sql
SELECT userid,
       MAX(qualification) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY "DATE") AS qualification, 
       COUNT(qualification) AS count
FROM   qualifications
GROUP  BY userid;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE qualifications (userid, qualification, "DATE") AS
SELECT 'One',   'Qual1', DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'One',   'Qual2', DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Two',   'Qual1', DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Three', 'Qual2', DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | USERID | QUALIFICATION | COUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | One | Qual2 | 2 |
> | Three | Qual2 | 1 |
> | Two | Qual1 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e01b7e552f3c7aaa10c8e77c0553ef61)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use two functions to compute the result you want. For example:

```
select userid, qualification, cnt
from (
  select t.*,
    count(*) over(partition by userid) as cnt,
    row_number() over(partition by userid order by date desc) as rn
  from Qualificaitons t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use **first_value** instead of max as agg function. read documentation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-first_value-function/).

```
select userid, count(qualification)OVER (PARTITION BY userid) as count_qual, 
first_value(qualification) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date desc) as qual_id 
from Qualificaitons
```